# Set all JTable cells unselectable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to create a JTable that simply displays data and does not allow any edits or selections.  I set all cells to be uneditable by running:

```
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, titles) {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

But I'm now trying to make all of the cells unselectable as well.  I found the `setRowSelectionAllowed` method which allowed me to disable the whole row being selected when a cell is selected, but that didn't stop the cell from being selectable.  I looked through the methods of `DefaultTableModel` but I didn't seen any `isCellSelectable` method.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In addition to returning `false` from `isCellEditable()`, add these invocations.

```
table.setFocusable(false);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
```