# jTable isCellEditable override not working

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to override the isCellEditable method of DefaultTableModel class to make my table cells non editable. I am trying achieve this by using anonymous inner class,

[image]

However the table cells are still editable and when trying to debug I found that the code not executing the overriden method instead it is directly calling the DefaultTableModel's isCellEditable method after instantiating DefaultTableModel class. Why is this happening???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `isCellEditable(int, int)` of the `JTable` class instead.

Note: The title of your question is very misleading because you are overriding the `isCellEditable(int, int)` of `DefaultTableModel`, not `JTable`.

Another note: I think it is obvious that you are using a GUI builder and my suggestion would be to **NOT** use it because you will not learn anything from GUI builders.

Comment: Hey Josh, that worked.. I know GUI builder is not the way but I am did not have time to spend on building the GUI so used it.. Thanks for the help.. \

Comment: No problem, you should definitely take the time to learn how to build a GUI without the assistance of a builder so you could be a more independent programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Check where the model is created. The table is initialized somewhere (where rows/cols data added to the table). In the place (now shown in your code) the inner class is replaced with another instance of `TableModel` (`DefaultTableModel` instance I think)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have checked it, debugged through the whole codes. I am sure it is using the model that I created in the code..

Comment: @RameshSivaraman: I'm surprised; `JTable` converts view to model coordinated and forwards the request to the model; see also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8291432/230513).

Comment: yeah, I really wanted to figure out why it is not overriding when it supposed to, however I got a fix meantime by overriding the jTable method as advised above..