# Limit JTable Selection to just one Row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

At the moment I'm developing an application which contains a `Jtable` listing some values from a DataBase table, I had set the cells from the JTable to be editable so I can save the changes from this values to the DB table, at the moment all that I could think of was retrieving all the updated values from the Jtable and the old values (I've save them in another ArrayList) and then send them to my method in order to make the update.

```
    MyTableModel myTable= (InsDefinicionTM) myTable.getModel();        
    for (int i = 0; i < myTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
        updateInsDefinicion(myTable.getUpdatedValue(i), oldValues.get(i));
    }
```

However this method is not the behavior I'm looking for (since I think that I could make something better) I wan't to edit just one value, and block the selection from the others fields form the table until I press some "save" button, anyone know how to prevent the other fields from the JTable to be editable or select able? I could use any of this two, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8291432/230513).

Comment: noup :/ doesn't work, maybe I didn't explain myself properly, I wan't to make my Jtable Non editable at first, then whenever I press a Edit button I want to make the cells editable but only for one row, so the changes are done by row!

Answer (score 9):

this is what you looking for

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

hope that helps